# How to make a flex box automatically adjust to an object with a percentage defined height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an svg file that I want to be contained in a flex box. The file does not have set size because I want the svg to scale based on the page/div size. Currently the containing flex adjusts to the width of the file but clips the height.

Ideally these flex boxes would remain in one row until the page width reaches below 768px. I'm relatively new to flex boxes so I'm not sure how to achieve this.

**This is the current result:**
[image: Current Output]

**This is the desired one:**
[image]

```css
.container {
background-color: red;
height:;
width:;
}

.map-flex {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
grid-gap: .5em;
  
margin: 0 30px;
padding: 15px 0; 
}

.box-1 {
flex-grow: 2 
}

.box-2 {
}

.jam-svg {
width: 100%;
height:;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="map-flex">
    <div class="box-1">
    <svg
                 class="jam-svg"
                 xmlns:mapsvg="http://mapsvg.com"
                 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 mapsvg:geoViewBox="-78.368846 18.525310 -76.183159 17.705724">
               
                <path
                   d="m 645.66777,185.2208 0,0 1.63,-0.16 2.83,-1.05 1.35,-0.89 1.56,-1.51 0.7,-0.57 0.82,-0.42 1.42,-0.17 4.92,-0.03 1.75,-0.24 1.25,-0.34 2.34,-1.29 1.77,-0.75 1.42,0.07 1.73,0.45 7.67,4.46 11.41,1.79 10.33,3.07 1.86,0.78 0.65,0.53 0.59,0.7 2.28,3.32 0.97,1.02 1.36,1.17 4.73,1.18 12.72,1.74 3.67,-0.43 9.73,-3.03 0.21,-0.07 0,0.01 2.8,6.77 5.14,8.78 6.56,6.96 9.51,7.15 -3.64,2.95 -18.03,4.57 -12.71,6.99 -7.28,2.12 -6.22,-1.61 2.43,-1.76 0.98,-1.25 1.36,-4.49 -6.3,2.31 -5.6,8.35 -6.08,1.85 -5.41,-1.55 -6.29,-2.91 -6.4,-1.65 -10.48,3.94 -27.43,2.38 -19.36,-2.95 -2.81,0.12 -2.63,0.51 -2.85,-0.38 -3.62,-2.52 -1.58,-3.31 -0.71,-4.24 -1.05,-3.64 -2.72,-1.55 -2.81,-0.87 -1.88,-2.06 -1.62,-2.44 -2.16,-1.93 -0.83,-0.2 0,-0.01 2.1,-3.31 2.2,-2.53 0.37,-1.17 0.17,-1.6 -0.2,-3.42 0.35,-2.13 1.54,-2.33 1.36,-0.64 1.4,-0.3 3.47,0.3 0.97,-0.18 0.55,-0.71 0,-1.26 -1.13,-2.08 -2.52,-3.58 -0.62,-1.22 -1.92,-6.88 -0.96,-1.63 -0.81,-2.08 -0.47,-2.26 0.14,-5.52 0.45,-2.98 0.6,-2.32 3.21,-2.97 6.54,4.49 2.65,3.62 0.64,0.65 0.73,0.63 2.31,1.58 2.63,1.25 16.52,5.25 2.46,1.42 1.32,0.14 z"
                   title="Saint Thomas"
                   id="JM-03" />
                <path
                   d="m 566.71777,142.3308 0,0 2.18,7.45 0.12,0.93 3.12,9.21 0.43,0.78 1.07,1.43 1.3,0.79 2.26,0.7 4.52,0.94 3.51,-0.64 1.68,-0.7 0.7,-1.08 0.78,-1.82 0.52,-0.8 0.67,-0.57 4.53,0.69 15.76,6.55 -3.21,2.97 -0.6,2.32 -0.45,2.98 -0.14,5.52 0.47,2.26 0.81,2.08 0.96,1.63 1.92,6.88 0.62,1.22 2.52,3.58 1.13,2.08 0,1.26 -0.55,0.71 -0.97,0.18 -3.47,-0.3 -1.4,0.3 -1.36,0.64 -1.54,2.33 -0.35,2.13 0.2,3.42 -0.17,1.6 -0.37,1.17 -2.2,2.53 -2.1,3.31 0,0.01 -9.65,-2.32 -2.61,-1.46 -5.37,-2.18 -7.24,0.43 -12.63,3 -5.4,0.66 -18.2,-0.66 0,-2.51 38.33,-2.27 -1.59,-1.53 1.93,-1.09 -0.31,-4.77 -2.92,-6.81 -3.45,-1.83 -5.18,-1.21 -9,0.45 -2.97,0.78 -3.47,1.43 -2.71,1.77 -0.6,1.35 -1.15,3.42 -2.3,-1.37 -6.21,-4.07 -4.58,-2.17 -1.13,-4.24 -2.38,-3.31 -0.93,0.2 -1.8,0.8 -0.87,0.2 -0.97,0 -0.82,-0.32 -0.64,-0.57 -0.47,-0.77 -0.64,-1.67 -0.37,-0.58 -0.3,-0.39 -2.53,-2.28 -0.04,-2.07 0.48,-3.2 2.07,-7.41 1.21,-3.07 1.07,-1.93 0.7,-0.53 0.65,-0.61 0.59,-0.7 0.45,-0.8 1.18,-2.64 0.06,-1.4 -0.34,-1.81 -2.31,-4.81 -0.55,-2.32 -0.17,-1.42 0.82,-9.62 4.74,-1.95 0.79,-0.65 0.85,-0.98 0.36,-0.95 0.47,-0.88 1.35,-0.61 2.13,-0.37 4.45,-0.02 2,-0.43 5.84,1.15 19.38,9.25 z"
                   title="Saint Andrew"
                   id="JM-02" />
                <path
                   d="m 584.16777,95.2508 0,0 -0.01,0 -1.04,1.19 -16.4,45.89 -19.38,-9.25 -5.84,-1.15 -2,0.43 -4.45,0.02 -2.13,0.37 -1.35,0.61 -0.47,0.88 -0.36,0.95 -0.85,0.98 -0.79,0.65 -4.74,1.95 -8.23,-3.34 -3.7,-3.61 -4.07,-5.62 -0.76,-1.57 -0.43,-3.12 -0.74,-2.97 -1.34,-2.86 -1.49,-1.62 -2.76,-2.02 -1.18,-1.62 -2.1,-5.04 -1.05,-1.33 -1.14,-0.83 -6.69,-0.73 -1.09,0.05 -1,0.2 -5.35,1.63 -6.69,-6.76 -2.32,-3.12 -0.42,-0.97 -0.56,-2.01 -0.49,-3.12 -1.07,-3.39 -1.48,-2.33 -4.33,-5.15 -0.73,-1.36 -0.13,-1.11 0.75,-8.24 -0.64,-1.38 -0.95,-1.34 -1.83,-1.77 -0.72,-1.3 -0.68,-2.64 -0.22,-1.91 -3.01,-13.45 -0.29,-1.66 0.01,0 6.4,-1.09 4.17,1.04 7.29,3.45 4.13,0.74 20.65,-0.88 4.02,-2.14 5.68,-0.69 4.61,0.36 4.26,0.72 2.48,3.2 -1.08,3.9 -0.01,4.96 3.89,3.56 12.42,7.84 10.97,6.41 1.8,3.57 3.24,9.65 2.07,3.18 3.34,2.05 6.35,1.76 18.06,1.41 3.99,0.89 z"
                   title="Saint Mary"
                   id="JM-05" />
                <path
                   d="m 524.35777,138.7708 0,0 -0.82,9.62 0.17,1.42 0.55,2.32 2.31,4.81 0.34,1.81 -0.06,1.4 -1.18,2.64 -0.45,0.8 -0.59,0.7 -0.65,0.61 -0.7,0.53 -1.07,1.93 -1.21,3.07 -2.07,7.41 -0.48,3.2 0.04,2.07 2.53,2.28 0.3,0.39 0.37,0.58 0.64,1.67 0.47,0.77 0.64,0.57 0.82,0.32 0.97,0 0.87,-0.2 1.8,-0.8 0.93,-0.2 2.38,3.31 1.13,4.24 -1.08,3.78 -1.64,3.88 -4.33,4.9 -1.34,2.82 -4.59,-0.55 -1.35,2.7 -1.37,8.37 -6.24,22.14 -4.63,6.59 -5.59,3.58 -4.6,0.04 -3.04,-1.38 -2.81,-1.91 -3.84,-1.52 -19.28,0 0,-2.72 7.37,-2.51 -3.76,-3.29 -4.72,-6.36 -3.66,-2.86 -4.26,-1.66 -10.05,-1.1 -9.11,3.18 -5.41,3.19 -1.64,-17.54 0.13,-1.19 -0.31,-1.54 -0.61,-1.64 -6.76,-9 -0.45,-0.86 -0.42,-1.01 -0.4,-2.13 -0.28,-2.81 -0.1,-12.81 -0.46,-1.85 -0.84,-2.42 -1.94,-3.62 -1.97,-2.96 -0.57,-0.67 -1.41,-2.23 -0.3,-1.32 -0.1,-1.8 0.81,-5.31 1,-3.43 1.3,-2.61 -1.38,-6.54 -9.91,-25.17 46.79,-5.95 7.1,-2.75 20.95,-11.82 5.35,-1.63 1,-0.2 1.09,-0.05 6.69,0.73 1.14,0.83 1.05,1.33 2.1,5.04 1.18,1.62 2.76,2.02 1.49,1.62 1.34,2.86 0.74,2.97 0.43,3.12 0.76,1.57 4.07,5.62 3.7,3.61 8.23,3.34 z"
                   title="Saint Catherine"
                   id="JM-14" />
                <path
                   d="m 455.42777,41.3608 0,0 0.29,1.66 3.01,13.45 0.22,1.91 0.68,2.64 0.72,1.3 1.83,1.77 0.95,1.34 0.64,1.38 -0.75,8.24 0.13,1.11 0.73,1.36 4.33,5.15 1.48,2.33 1.07,3.39 0.49,3.12 0.56,2.01 0.42,0.97 2.32,3.12 6.69,6.76 -20.95,11.82 -7.1,2.75 -46.79,5.95 -31.59,-0.43 -17.12,-3.15 -6.72,-2.7 -1.79,-0.29 -1.44,-0.03 -11.83,2.7 -0.85,0.4 -2.44,1.93 -1.3,0.74 -2.49,1.03 -1.65,0.3 -1.52,0.07 -8.87,-1.53 -8.2,-2.72 13.85,-66.16 0.1,-1.8 -0.11,-1.68 -1.86,-2.32 -0.49,-1.04 -0.01,-1.32 0.94,-2.31 0.28,-2.13 -0.28,-2.66 -4,-10.41 -0.28,-3.02 0.76,-7.31 0.12,-0.76 3.6,0.27 9.11,2.25 7.19,4.37 11.07,-2.88 17.88,0.05 18.39,2.08 12.67,3.26 1.56,1.65 1.29,4.55 1.69,1.57 2.04,0.02 1.89,-0.9 1.11,-1.17 -0.27,-0.69 15.59,2.74 1.93,1.17 5.88,5.19 1.82,1.17 11.39,0.39 11.99,-2.02 z"
                   title="Saint Ann"
                   id="JM-06" />
                <path
                   d="m 736.90777,188.6708 0,0 2.43,5.88 -0.21,0.07 -9.73,3.03 -3.67,0.43 -12.72,-1.74 -4.73,-1.18 -1.36,-1.17 -0.97,-1.02 -2.28,-3.32 -0.59,-0.7 -0.65,-0.53 -1.86,-0.78 -10.33,-3.07 -11.41,-1.79 -7.67,-4.46 -1.73,-0.45 -1.42,-0.07 -1.77,0.75 -2.34,1.29 -1.25,0.34 -1.75,0.24 -4.92,0.03 -1.42,0.17 -0.82,0.42 -0.7,0.57 -1.56,1.51 -1.35,0.89 -2.83,1.05 -1.63,0.16 -1.32,-0.14 -2.46,-1.42 -16.52,-5.25 -2.63,-1.25 -2.31,-1.58 -0.73,-0.63 -0.64,-0.65 -2.65,-3.62 -6.54,-4.49 -15.76,-6.55 -4.53,-0.69 -0.67,0.57 -0.52,0.8 -0.78,1.82 -0.7,1.08 -1.68,0.7 -3.51,0.64 -4.52,-0.94 -2.26,-0.7 -1.3,-0.79 -1.07,-1.43 -0.43,-0.78 -3.12,-9.21 -0.12,-0.93 -2.18,-7.45 16.4,-45.89 1.04,-1.19 0.01,0 2,0.44 5.13,2.74 6.64,6.72 5.11,3.32 5.92,1.86 11.59,-0.74 6.07,4.3 1.94,0.5 1.75,1.68 2.14,1.52 2.88,0.69 26.2,0 1.83,1.11 2.74,5.26 1.27,1.61 25.68,4.84 13.35,4.85 1.7,7.63 9.91,9.52 7.7,11.05 11.19,24.52 z"
                   title="Portland"
                   id="JM-04" />
                <path
                   d="m 575.25777,210.1608 0,0 -0.82,-0.79 -1.76,-1.71 -4.57,-1.04 -10.54,-0.15 -7.15,0.16 -4.99,-2.98 1.15,-3.42 0.6,-1.35 2.71,-1.77 3.47,-1.43 2.97,-0.78 9,-0.45 5.18,1.21 3.45,1.83 2.92,6.81 0.31,4.77 -1.93,1.09 z"
                   title="Kingston"
                   id="JM-01" />
                <path
                   d="m 158.43777,84.4608 0,0 3.82,8.25 2.01,2.42 0.86,0.44 0.72,0.54 0.63,0.69 0.53,0.7 1.03,1.83 2.79,8.88 -0.16,3.49 -3.32,9.71 -5.27,2.63 -1.2,0.99 -1.55,1.57 -3.84,6.13 -2.22,4.66 -0.58,2.27 -0.12,1.1 0.08,1.03 0.49,1.93 0.32,0.88 -0.79,5.44 -6.87,19.87 -2.43,4.74 -0.01,0 -5.35,-12.44 -2.76,-4 -2.99,-2.08 -3.48,-1.78 -2.79,-0.73 -2.15,-1.93 -1.68,-4.43 -2.13,-8.7 -6.56,-13.31 -8.69,-4.89 -25.69,0.64 -15.69,-2.66 -5.73,-0.06 -3.28,3.02 -2.69,1.48 -2.35,-0.49 -8.59,-3.47 -0.87,-0.54 -4.88,-0.79 -10.74,-3.46 -6.02,-0.76 -6.13,-1.52 -5.94,-3.99 -4.37,-5.66 -1.54,-6.41 1.93,-3.05 5.17,-3.66 2.45,-3.08 0.44,-2.11 0,0 3.16,0.25 18.83,2.73 1.89,0.02 1.79,-0.36 1.72,-1.37 13.1,-15.48 1.98,-0.53 43.33,-0.2 3.23,0.45 3.05,0.86 19.21,11.17 7.64,1.4 29.25,1.73 z"
                   title="Westmoreland"
                   id="JM-10" />
                <path
                   d="m 317.60777,18.2908 0,0 -0.12,0.76 -0.76,7.31 0.28,3.02 4,10.41 0.28,2.66 -0.28,2.13 -0.94,2.31 0.01,1.32 0.49,1.04 1.86,2.32 0.11,1.68 -0.1,1.8 -13.85,66.16 -15.59,-10.87 -5,-2.21 -1.11,0.04 -13.34,-2.01 -2.01,-0.06 -1.95,0.53 -2.55,1.2 -3.87,2.36 -2.14,0.8 -4.49,1.13 -49.24,-4.99 15.88,-99.47 0.13,-0.64 24.77,5.43 33.95,0.65 15,3.67 20.58,1.52 z"
                   title="Trelawny"
                   id="JM-07" />
                <path
                   d="m 223.30777,7.0208 0,0 -0.13,0.64 -15.88,99.47 -39.95,14.28 3.32,-9.71 0.16,-3.49 -2.79,-8.88 -1.03,-1.83 -0.53,-0.7 -0.63,-0.69 -0.72,-0.54 -0.86,-0.44 -2.01,-2.42 -3.82,-8.25 -4.43,-8.95 -0.87,-1.17 -1.73,-1.65 -4.87,-2.57 -1.26,-0.91 -0.72,-0.77 -1.74,-3.97 -3.94,-7.29 -0.98,-2.3 -0.54,-2.65 -0.86,-1.79 -0.58,-1 -5.68,-4.71 -1.19,-1.47 -0.63,-1.3 2.3,-8.25 0.19,-1.11 0.05,-3.5 0,0 2.7,0.99 3.86,0.97 3.98,-0.63 3.54,-2.51 0.34,-2.41 -0.1,-2.82 2.16,-3.8 7.9,-10.15 3.6,-3.37 6.16,-2.8 14.11,-2.32 15.99,0.61 28.1,6.16 0.01,0 z"
                   title="Saint James"
                   id="JM-08" />
                <path
                   d="m 256.53777,112.1208 0,0 1.76,32.93 23.81,98.91 0.86,1.65 0,0.01 -8.31,-1.43 -47.28,2.72 -2.39,-0.45 -7.27,-4.95 -12.28,-6.1 -3.08,-2.42 -1.52,-2.78 -3.62,-9.4 -0.73,-2.97 -1.32,-2.33 -6.24,-2.23 -1.96,-1.59 -0.51,-7.7 0.62,-9.25 -2.17,-7.78 -8.88,-3.27 -24.19,-0.21 -5.57,-2.08 -2.91,-6.75 0.01,0 2.43,-4.74 6.87,-19.87 0.79,-5.44 -0.32,-0.88 -0.49,-1.93 -0.08,-1.03 0.12,-1.1 0.58,-2.27 2.22,-4.66 3.84,-6.13 1.55,-1.57 1.2,-0.99 5.27,-2.63 39.95,-14.28 49.24,4.99 z"
                   title="Saint Elizabeth"
                   id="JM-11" />
                <path
                   d="m 286.88777,108.1708 0,0 1.11,-0.04 5,2.21 15.59,10.87 0.83,5.47 37.98,77.98 -0.48,2.08 -0.98,2.89 -0.11,1.78 0.18,2.48 0.77,4.97 0.61,2.22 0.6,1.58 1.62,2.15 3.99,3.46 0.77,1.29 0.35,1.22 -0.15,1.16 -2.07,6.83 -0.71,4.48 -0.38,0.95 -0.58,0.68 -0.72,0.51 -0.92,0.2 -1.08,0.06 -3.11,-0.38 -1.01,0.31 -0.71,0.47 -0.99,0.93 0,0.01 -0.36,-0.21 -7.72,-2.85 -8.13,-1.08 -6.43,2.66 -7.39,5.01 -7.4,0.66 -15.23,-4.42 -6.66,-1.14 0,-0.01 -0.86,-1.65 -23.81,-98.91 -1.76,-32.93 4.49,-1.13 2.14,-0.8 3.87,-2.36 2.55,-1.2 1.95,-0.53 2.01,0.06 13.34,2.01 z"
                   title="Manchester"
                   id="JM-12" />
                <path
                   d="m 130.95777,29.1008 0,0 -0.05,3.5 -0.19,1.11 -2.3,8.25 0.63,1.3 1.19,1.47 5.68,4.71 0.58,1 0.86,1.79 0.54,2.65 0.98,2.3 3.94,7.29 1.74,3.97 0.72,0.77 1.26,0.91 4.87,2.57 1.73,1.65 0.87,1.17 4.43,8.95 -29.25,-1.73 -7.64,-1.4 -19.21,-11.17 -3.05,-0.86 -3.23,-0.45 -43.33,0.2 -1.98,0.53 -13.1,15.48 -1.72,1.37 -1.79,0.36 -1.89,-0.02 -18.83,-2.73 -3.16,-0.25 0,0 0.58,-2.73 -0.5,-11.08 0.67,-3.14 2.65,-4.35 0.3,-2.77 1.22,-1.45 5.43,-0.45 3.4,-2.23 2.77,-4.31 3.6,-2.93 5.85,1.94 3.6,-10.41 10.71,-9.88 12.44,-4.13 8.97,6.85 5.18,-6.13 5.54,-0.12 6.48,2.39 7.93,1.57 22.58,-2.78 7.53,0.04 3.77,1.41 z"
                   title="Hanover"
                   id="JM-09" />
                <path
                   d="m 406.39777,124.8908 0,0 9.91,25.17 1.38,6.54 -1.3,2.61 -1,3.43 -0.81,5.31 0.1,1.8 0.3,1.32 1.41,2.23 0.57,0.67 1.97,2.96 1.94,3.62 0.84,2.42 0.46,1.85 0.1,12.81 0.28,2.81 0.4,2.13 0.42,1.01 0.45,0.86 6.76,9 0.61,1.64 0.31,1.54 -0.13,1.19 1.64,17.54 -2.46,1.46 -5.73,11.46 -1.36,3.34 2.64,10.16 -2.54,1.01 -4.43,2.7 -2.56,1.07 0.91,1.93 0.61,3.71 0.85,2.33 -3.73,-1.7 -3.75,-0.18 -3.64,1.29 -3.37,2.84 6.13,3.79 6.47,1.43 6.79,-0.57 7.03,-2.15 3.54,13.78 -1.07,6.32 -8.53,2.65 -7.27,-0.36 -6.51,-1.47 -6.44,-3.12 -30.3,-27.16 -6.28,-7.92 -25.72,-15 0,-0.01 0.99,-0.93 0.71,-0.47 1.01,-0.31 3.11,0.38 1.08,-0.06 0.92,-0.2 0.72,-0.51 0.58,-0.68 0.38,-0.95 0.71,-4.48 2.07,-6.83 0.15,-1.16 -0.35,-1.22 -0.77,-1.29 -3.99,-3.46 -1.62,-2.15 -0.6,-1.58 -0.61,-2.22 -0.77,-4.97 -0.18,-2.48 0.11,-1.78 0.98,-2.89 0.48,-2.08 -37.98,-77.98 -0.83,-5.47 8.2,2.72 8.87,1.53 1.52,-0.07 1.65,-0.3 2.49,-1.03 1.3,-0.74 2.44,-1.93 0.85,-0.4 11.83,-2.7 1.44,0.03 1.79,0.29 6.72,2.7 17.12,3.15 31.59,0.43 z"
                   title="Clarendon"
                   id="JM-13" />
              </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not CSS as much as it is your SVG.
I imported it into Sketch and drew a new artboard around it and re-exported it. I also ran it through https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ to make sure it's lean and clean.

For some details your `viewBox` was all messed up and so `auto` height for the SVG would mean some of the map would be cut off. That was the main issue. The rest I did made sure the SVG was clean and removed some unneeded attributes.

An added bonus to the new SVG code is that you can now add `fill="currentColor"` in a single place (the wrapping group) and your SVG will take the color of the current font color it is in.

I also cleaned up your CSS a bit. `grid-gap` is now `gap` as it also works for flex. And empty declarations like this `height:;` run the risk of some browsers handling what you mean here differently (I'm looking at your Safari). It's always good to be explicit.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.map-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 15px 0; 
}

.box-1 {
  flex-grow: 2 
}

.jam-svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="map-flex">
    <div class="box-1">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 764 303">
        <g fill="#000" fill-rule="nonzero">
          <path d="M645.7 185.2l1.6-.1 2.8-1.1 1.4-.9 1.5-1.5.7-.6.9-.4 1.4-.1 4.9-.1 1.7-.2 1.3-.4 2.3-1.2 1.8-.8 1.4.1 1.8.4 7.6 4.5 11.4 1.8 10.4 3 1.8.8.7.6.6.7 2.2 3.3 1 1 1.4 1.2 4.7 1.1 12.7 1.8 3.7-.4 9.7-3.1h.2l2.8 6.7 5.2 8.8 6.5 7 9.5 7.1-3.6 3-18 4.5-12.7 7-7.3 2.2-6.2-1.7 2.4-1.7 1-1.3 1.3-4.5-6.3 2.4-5.6 8.3-6 1.9-5.5-1.6-6.2-2.9-6.4-1.7-10.5 4-27.5 2.4-19.3-3-2.8.1-2.7.5-2.8-.3-3.6-2.6-1.6-3.3-.7-4.2-1.1-3.6-2.7-1.6-2.8-.9-1.9-2-1.6-2.5-2.2-1.9-.8-.2 2.1-3.3 2.2-2.5.4-1.2.2-1.6-.2-3.4.3-2.2 1.5-2.3 1.4-.6 1.4-.3 3.5.3.9-.2.6-.7v-1.3l-1.1-2.1-2.6-3.5-.6-1.3-1.9-6.8-1-1.7-.8-2.1-.4-2.2.1-5.5.5-3 .6-2.3 3.2-3 6.5 4.5 2.7 3.6.6.7.7.6 2.3 1.6 2.7 1.2 16.5 5.3 2.4 1.4 1.4.1z" />
          <path d="M566.7 142.3l2.2 7.5.1.9 3.1 9.2.5.8 1 1.4 1.3.8 2.3.7 4.5 1 3.5-.7 1.7-.7.7-1.1.8-1.8.5-.8.7-.5 4.5.6 15.8 6.6-3.2 3-.6 2.3-.5 3-.1 5.5.4 2.2.8 2.1 1 1.7 1.9 6.8.6 1.3 2.6 3.5 1.1 2.1v1.3l-.6.7-.9.2-3.5-.3-1.4.3-1.4.6-1.5 2.3-.3 2.2.2 3.4-.2 1.6-.4 1.2-2.2 2.5-2.1 3.3-9.6-2.3-2.6-1.5-5.4-2.2-7.3.5-12.6 3-5.4.6-18.2-.6V214l38.3-2.3-1.5-1.5 1.9-1.1-.3-4.8-2.9-6.8-3.5-1.8-5.2-1.2-9 .4-2.9.8-3.5 1.4-2.7 1.8-.6 1.3-1.2 3.5-2.3-1.4-6.2-4.1-4.6-2.2-1.1-4.2-2.4-3.3-.9.2-1.8.8-.9.2h-.9l-.9-.3-.6-.6-.5-.8-.6-1.6-.4-.6-.3-.4-2.5-2.3-.1-2.1.5-3.2 2.1-7.4 1.2-3 1.1-2 .7-.5.6-.6.6-.7.5-.8 1.1-2.6.1-1.4-.3-1.9-2.3-4.8-.6-2.3-.2-1.4.9-9.6 4.7-2 .8-.6.8-1 .4-1 .5-.8 1.3-.6 2.1-.4h4.5l2-.5 5.8 1.2 19.4 9.2z" />
          <path d="M584.2 95.3l-1.1 1.1-16.4 45.9-19.4-9.2-5.8-1.2-2 .5H535l-2.1.4-1.3.6-.5.8-.4 1-.8 1-.8.6-4.7 2-8.3-3.4-3.7-3.6-4-5.6-.8-1.6-.4-3.1-.8-3-1.3-2.8-1.5-1.6-2.8-2.1-1.1-1.6-2.1-5-1.1-1.3-1.1-.9-6.7-.7h-1.1l-1 .2-5.4 1.7-6.7-6.8-2.3-3.1-.4-1-.6-2-.4-3.1-1.1-3.4-1.5-2.3-4.3-5.2-.8-1.3-.1-1.1.8-8.3-.7-1.4-.9-1.3-1.9-1.8-.7-1.3-.7-2.6-.2-1.9-3-13.5-.3-1.6 6.4-1.1 4.2 1 7.3 3.5 4.1.7 20.7-.9 4-2.1 5.7-.7 4.6.4 4.2.7 2.5 3.2L518 50v4.9l3.9 3.6 12.4 7.8 11 6.4 1.8 3.6 3.3 9.7 2 3.1 3.4 2.1 6.3 1.8 18.1 1.4 4 .9z" />
          <path d="M524.4 138.8l-.9 9.6.2 1.4.6 2.3 2.3 4.8.3 1.9-.1 1.4-1.1 2.6-.5.8-.6.7-.6.6-.7.5-1.1 2-1.2 3-2.1 7.4-.5 3.2.1 2.1 2.5 2.3.3.4.4.6.6 1.6.5.8.6.6.9.3h.9l.9-.2 1.8-.8.9-.2 2.4 3.3 1.1 4.2-1 3.8-1.7 3.9-4.3 4.9-1.4 2.8-4.5-.5-1.4 2.7-1.4 8.3-6.2 22.2-4.6 6.6-5.6 3.6h-4.6l-3.1-1.4-2.8-1.9-3.8-1.5h-19.3v-2.7l7.4-2.5-3.8-3.3-4.7-6.4-3.7-2.9-4.2-1.6-10.1-1.1-9.1 3.2-5.4 3.2-1.6-17.6.1-1.2-.3-1.5-.6-1.7-6.8-9-.4-.8-.5-1-.4-2.2-.2-2.8-.1-12.8-.5-1.8-.8-2.4-2-3.7-1.9-2.9-.6-.7-1.4-2.2-.3-1.3-.1-1.8.8-5.4 1-3.4 1.3-2.6-1.4-6.5-9.9-25.2 46.8-6 7.1-2.7 20.9-11.8 5.4-1.7 1-.2h1.1l6.7.7 1.1.9 1.1 1.3 2.1 5 1.1 1.6 2.8 2.1 1.5 1.6 1.3 2.8.8 3 .4 3.1.8 1.6 4 5.6 3.7 3.6 8.3 3.4z" />
          <path d="M455.4 41.4l.3 1.6 3 13.5.2 1.9.7 2.6.7 1.3 1.9 1.8.9 1.3.7 1.4-.8 8.3.1 1.1.8 1.3 4.3 5.2 1.5 2.3 1.1 3.4.4 3.1.6 2 .4 1 2.3 3.1 6.7 6.8-20.9 11.8-7.1 2.7-46.8 6-31.6-.4-17.1-3.2-6.7-2.7-1.8-.3h-1.5l-11.8 2.7-.8.4-2.5 1.9-1.3.8-2.5 1-1.6.3-1.5.1-8.9-1.6-8.2-2.7 13.8-66.1.1-1.8-.1-1.7-1.8-2.3-.5-1.1v-1.3l.9-2.3.3-2.1-.3-2.7-4-10.4-.3-3 .8-7.3.1-.8 3.6.3 9.1 2.2 7.2 4.4 11.1-2.9 17.9.1 18.3 2 12.7 3.3 1.6 1.6 1.3 4.6 1.7 1.6h2l1.9-.9 1.1-1.2-.3-.7 15.6 2.8 1.9 1.1 5.9 5.2L432 43l11.4.4 12-2zM736.9 188.7l2.4 5.9h-.2l-9.7 3.1-3.7.4-12.7-1.8-4.7-1.1-1.4-1.2-1-1-2.2-3.3-.6-.7-.7-.6-1.8-.8-10.4-3-11.4-1.8-7.6-4.5-1.8-.4-1.4-.1-1.8.8-2.3 1.2-1.3.4-1.7.2-4.9.1-1.4.1-.9.4-.7.6-1.5 1.5-1.4.9-2.8 1.1-1.6.1-1.4-.1-2.4-1.4-16.5-5.3-2.7-1.2-2.3-1.6-.7-.6-.6-.7-2.7-3.6-6.5-4.5-15.8-6.6-4.5-.6-.7.5-.5.8-.8 1.8-.7 1.1-1.7.7-3.5.7-4.5-1-2.3-.7-1.3-.8-1-1.4-.5-.8-3.1-9.2-.1-.9-2.2-7.5 16.4-45.9 1.1-1.1 2 .4 5.1 2.7 6.6 6.8 5.1 3.3 6 1.8 11.6-.7 6 4.3 2 .5 1.7 1.7 2.2 1.5 2.8.7h26.2l1.9 1.1 2.7 5.3 1.3 1.6 25.7 4.8 13.3 4.9 1.7 7.6 9.9 9.5 7.7 11.1 11.2 24.5zM575.3 210.2l-.9-.8-1.7-1.7-4.6-1.1-10.5-.1-7.2.1-5-2.9 1.2-3.5.6-1.3 2.7-1.8 3.5-1.4 2.9-.8 9-.4 5.2 1.2 3.5 1.8 2.9 6.8.3 4.8-1.9 1.1zM158.4 84.5l3.9 8.2 2 2.4.8.5.7.5.7.7.5.7 1 1.8 2.8 8.9-.1 3.5-3.4 9.7-5.2 2.6-1.2 1-1.6 1.6-3.8 6.1-2.2 4.7-.6 2.3-.1 1.1v1l.5 1.9.4.9-.8 5.4-6.9 19.9-2.4 4.8-5.4-12.5-2.8-4-2.9-2.1-3.5-1.7-2.8-.8-2.2-1.9-1.6-4.4-2.2-8.7-6.5-13.3-8.7-4.9-25.7.6-15.7-2.7h-5.7l-3.3 3-2.7 1.5-2.4-.5-8.5-3.5-.9-.5-4.9-.8-10.7-3.5-6.1-.7-6.1-1.5-5.9-4-4.4-5.7-1.5-6.4 1.9-3.1L7.4 89l2.4-3.1.5-2.1 3.1.2 18.8 2.8h1.9l1.8-.4 1.7-1.3 13.1-15.5 2-.5 43.4-.2 3.2.4 3 .9 19.2 11.1 7.7 1.4 29.2 1.8z" />
          <path d="M317.6 18.3l-.1.8-.8 7.3.3 3 4 10.4.3 2.7-.3 2.1-.9 2.3v1.3l.5 1.1 1.8 2.3.1 1.7-.1 1.8-13.8 66.1-15.6-10.9-5-2.2-1.1.1-13.4-2-2-.1-1.9.5-2.6 1.2-3.8 2.4-2.2.8-4.5 1.1-49.2-5 15.9-99.4.1-.7 24.8 5.5 33.9.6 15 3.7z" />
          <path d="M223.3 7l-.1.7-15.9 99.4-40 14.3 3.4-9.7.1-3.5-2.8-8.9-1-1.8-.5-.7-.7-.7-.7-.5-.8-.5-2-2.4-3.9-8.2-4.4-9-.9-1.2-1.7-1.6-4.9-2.6-1.2-.9-.7-.8-1.8-3.9-3.9-7.3-1-2.3-.5-2.7-.9-1.8-.6-1-5.7-4.7-1.2-1.4-.6-1.3 2.3-8.3.2-1.1.1-3.5 2.7 1 3.8 1 4-.7 3.5-2.5.4-2.4-.1-2.8 2.1-3.8 7.9-10.2 3.6-3.3 6.2-2.8L179.2.3l16 .6L223.3 7z" />
          <path d="M256.5 112.1l1.8 33 23.8 98.9.9 1.6-8.3-1.4-47.3 2.7-2.4-.4-7.3-5-12.3-6.1-3-2.4-1.6-2.8-3.6-9.4-.7-3-1.3-2.3-6.3-2.2-1.9-1.6-.5-7.7.6-9.3-2.2-7.7-8.9-3.3-24.2-.2-5.5-2.1-2.9-6.7 2.4-4.8 6.9-19.9.8-5.4-.4-.9-.5-1.9v-1l.1-1.1.6-2.3 2.2-4.7 3.8-6.1 1.6-1.6 1.2-1 5.2-2.6 40-14.3 49.2 5z" />
          <path d="M286.9 108.2l1.1-.1 5 2.2 15.6 10.9.8 5.5 38 78-.5 2-1 2.9-.1 1.8.2 2.5.8 5 .6 2.2.6 1.6 1.6 2.1 4 3.5.8 1.3.3 1.2-.1 1.1-2.1 6.9-.7 4.5-.4.9-.6.7-.7.5-.9.2-1.1.1-3.1-.4-1 .3-.7.5-1 .9-.4-.2-7.7-2.9-8.1-1-6.5 2.6-7.3 5-7.4.7-15.3-4.4-6.6-1.2-.9-1.6-23.8-98.9-1.8-33 4.5-1.1 2.2-.8 3.8-2.4 2.6-1.2 1.9-.5 2 .1 13.4 2zM131 29.1l-.1 3.5-.2 1.1-2.3 8.3.6 1.3 1.2 1.4 5.7 4.7.6 1 .9 1.8.5 2.7 1 2.3 3.9 7.3 1.8 3.9.7.8 1.2.9 4.9 2.6 1.7 1.6.9 1.2 4.4 9-29.2-1.8-7.7-1.4-19.2-11.1-3-.9-3.2-.4-43.4.2-2 .5-13.1 15.5-1.7 1.3-1.8.4h-1.9L13.4 84l-3.1-.2.5-2.7-.5-11.1.7-3.2 2.7-4.3.3-2.8 1.2-1.4 5.4-.5 3.4-2.2 2.8-4.3 3.6-2.9 5.8 1.9 3.6-10.4L50.5 30 63 25.9l8.9 6.8 5.2-6.1 5.6-.1 6.4 2.4 8 1.5 22.6-2.7h7.5l3.8 1.4z" />
          <path d="M406.4 124.9l9.9 25.2 1.4 6.5-1.3 2.6-1 3.4-.8 5.4.1 1.8.3 1.3 1.4 2.2.6.7 1.9 2.9 2 3.7.8 2.4.5 1.8.1 12.8.2 2.8.4 2.2.5 1 .4.8 6.8 9 .6 1.7.3 1.5-.1 1.2 1.6 17.6-2.5 1.4-5.7 11.5-1.3 3.3 2.6 10.2-2.5 1-4.5 2.7-2.5 1.1.9 1.9.6 3.7.8 2.3-3.7-1.7-3.7-.2-3.7 1.3-3.4 2.9 6.2 3.8 6.4 1.4 6.8-.6 7.1-2.1 3.5 13.8-1.1 6.3-8.5 2.6-7.3-.3-6.5-1.5-6.4-3.1-30.3-27.2-6.3-7.9-25.7-15 1-.9.7-.5 1-.3 3.1.4 1.1-.1.9-.2.7-.5.6-.7.4-.9.7-4.5 2.1-6.9.1-1.1-.3-1.2-.8-1.3-4-3.5-1.6-2.1-.6-1.6-.6-2.2-.8-5-.2-2.5.1-1.8 1-2.9.5-2-38-78-.8-5.5 8.2 2.7 8.9 1.6 1.5-.1 1.6-.3 2.5-1 1.3-.8 2.5-1.9.8-.4 11.8-2.7h1.5l1.8.3 6.7 2.7 17.1 3.2 31.6.4z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam
        malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```